# Copy the data generated by locale-gen to another computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locale

I am using an OpenVZ VPS with only 128M RAM.
The RAM is so limited that I cannot get `locale-gen` to run successfully. The script **always** gets killed during the operation.

`Killed                  localedef -i $input -c -f $charset -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias $locale`

Is there any way that I can set correct locale information manually? e.g. run the command on another computer and copy necessary files?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, it won't help to copy locale data generated elsewhere and **it might corrupt the system** since commands like `cd` and `ls` depend on it.

It should suffice to run `locale-gen` on a 128M RAM VPS.

If it keeps failing, try switching to a locale with less footprint. Any locale ending with `.UTF-8` requires more memory and CPU time to generate. In most case, switching from `en_US.UTF-8` to `en_US.iso88591` can save some memory.

So instead of

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

It's worth trying

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.iso88591
```